# $FormatEnumerationLimit = -1 within a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have created a PowerShell script, but the output gets cut off with ...}

If I type $FormatEnumerationLimit = -1 before I run the script, it works. But the problem is I can't seem to include this command within my script. If I add this command at the top of my script, it doesn't work.

How can I get this included in the script?? Sorry I don't think the script copied over correctly in the window.

```
$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1
Get-ChildItem hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\software\nameofsoftware | ForEach-    Object {
Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath
} | Foreach-Object {
$Properties = @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Header= $_.Header
    True= $_.True
    Schedule = $_.Schedule
}

New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
} | FL | Out-File C:\test.txt -Width 10000
 Send-MailMessage -from "joe@joe.com" -to "joe@joe.com" -subject "Test" 
-smtpserver 192.168.5.2 -port 25 -Attachments C:\test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FL output is meant for the screen, rather than for files. Besides, why package all the information up to an object only to try and take it apart immediately? You could output the information in the format you want, directly:

```
} | Foreach-Object {
    "Name: "     + $_.Name
    "Header: "   + $_.Header
    "True: "     + $_.True
    "Schedule: " + $_.Schedule
} | Set-Content C:\test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you!! You wouldn't by chance know how to add a space after each section of data? For example, once I get name, header, true, schedule it will give me the next name, header, true, schedule but not leave any spaces between - making all the data scrunched together and hard to interpret. Thank you again!

Comment: Nevermind - I added "" right below the line "Schedule: " + $_.Schedule and it added a space. Thank you so much!